# key_compare vs key_comp in C++

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I want to do some operation on a set object with a generic type which is dependant on the key comparator.

Is there any difference between the following two implementations?

```
template <class SetType, class KeyType>
bool CompareFirst1(SetType set, KeyType key)
{
    return typename SetType::key_compare()(*set.begin(), key);
}

template <class SetType, class KeyType>
bool CompareFirst2(SetType set, KeyType key)
{
    return set.key_comp()(*set.begin(), key);
}
```

Comment: [cppreference -search **key_compare**](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=key_compare)??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: don't let yourself become confused by cppreference.com's flakey search function. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set mentions both.

Comment: @SteveJessop THX for the enlightment :) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The first default constructs a new object the type used as the comparison object for the Set.  The second returns and uses a copy of the comparison object that the set is using.

The difference is that if the user passed a comparison object in during construction, it might have an internal state that is different than a default constructed comparison object.  Or it might not even be possible to default construct that object.  You want to use the second form.

Comment: I can't find any standard reference for `key_compare`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `key_compare` is well-defined in §23.2.4. However, I think `key_comp` is underspecified.

Comment: @JosephMansfield [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=key_comp) seems to state it vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a standard associative container, then `key_compare` is the comparator type, and `key_comp()` is a member function which returns the set's comparator object. So the first will create a new object of that type, which might be different from the one in the set, and so might give incorrect results.

You want to use the second.